# Subscript out of range when trying to set a Workbook obj variable

Tags: excel, vba

I can't understand what I am doing wrong But I am getting an error 9 (subscript out of range) on the first SET line.

I declared a module-level public variable as BurdenMaster, spelling is correct and everything. Do I have to open the workbook in order to set it ? I am at a loss because this didn't happen last time I ran the macro.

Thanks,

```
'STATIC FILES
theFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
tTemplate = theFilePath & "JE_Upload_Template.xltx"
tBurdenMaster = theFilePath & "Burdens_Master.xlsm"

'For updating the burden amounts in the master
Set BurdenMaster = Workbooks(VBA.Replace(tBurdenMaster, theFilePath, ""))
Set BurdenSched = BurdenMaster.Sheets("BurdenSchedule")
```

Comment: Is the workbook open? If it's not opened, it's not in the `Application.Workbooks` collection.

Comment: You have to set `On Error Resume Next` and check to see if `BurdenMaster is Nothing` to see if the workbook is already open. Then open it if not.

Comment: take `VBA` out or the `Replace` statement: `Workbooks(Replace(tBurdenMaster, theFilePath, ""))`

Comment: @Zac that's useless advice at best, and a bad idea at worst. Fully-qualified library calls are always a good idea. That way if you have your own `Replace` function you know which one this is invoking.

Comment: Thanks all. I wasn't sure to be honest if you could declare and set a variable on a closed workbook, but I guess you can't really. Seems I'll have to make the adjustment to my project. I Used your suggestion PeterT with an if statement to open and declare the WB and WS.